# how to get time difference stored in two variables in shell script

Tags: shell, time

script is as follows:

---

```
starttime=`date +"%T"`

echo $starttime

`sleep 2s`

endtime=`date +"%T"`

echo $endtime

totaltime=$(expr $endtime - $starttime)

echo "$totaltime"
```

---

i want to substract `$endtime` from `$starttime` and want to show the time difference

but whenever i run it;

it shows this error

> "expr: non-numeric argument"

Comment: 00:00:00 is not a numeric argument. Use `%s` argument to time for a numeric representation(in seconds from epoch).

Comment: Store `starttime_s` and `endtime_s` with `$(date +%s)` to store seconds since epoch. You can then simply `endtime_s - starttime_s` and convert the seconds into whatever format you like. Saving only time info with `%T` loses all *date* reference, so there is no way to go back with `date -d <datestr>`. If you are guaranteed your times are only minutes/hours apart, you can convert manually to seconds.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Its working fine but how could i recognized at what time it started and what time it ends...  as it showing something like "1455701713
1455701715
2"    Answer is correct but want to know at what time it starts and at what time it ends

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to measure the elapsed of your shell script (or part of it). In this case I would use internal variable SECONDS this way:

```
SECONDS=0
... your stuff here...
echo "Elapsed: ${SECONDS}"
# and/or... if you (also) want HH:MM:SS
hh=$(( SECONDS / 3600 ))
mm=$(( ( SECONDS / 60 ) % 60 ))
ss=$(( SECONDS % 60 ))
printf "Elapsed: %02d:%02d:%02d\n", $hh $mm $ss
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comment. If you have saved `starttime_s` and `endtime_s` with `$(date +%s)` and taken the difference `endtime_s - starttime_s` (stored in `tmdiff`), you now have the difference in seconds. Your start time is simply:

```
date -d @${starttime_s}
```

(you can output it with `echo $(date -d @${starttime_s})` and add any format of your choosing at the end. e.g. `echo $(date -d @${starttime_s} +%yourfmt)`)

Your end time is:

```
endtime=$((starttime_s + tmdiff))
date -d @${endtime}
```

(or just)

```
date -d @${endtime_s}
```

You are just using the `date -d` command which takes a given time as input to the `date` command.